# VirtualBox Bridging Switching all IP traffic to all Guest vs all Host via bat script

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

From "[Set Network Adaptor For Exclusive Use of Guest](https://superuser.com/questions/278515/virtualbox-set-network-adaptor-for-exclusive-use-of-guest-vm)" I was able to run a private tfpt booted network from either a Guest OS (Windows Server 2003) or the HOST OS (Windows Server 2012). This allows me to run current and legacy software tests on an embedded system.

I want to have a script that selects/deselects the drivers on the NIC card I am bridging.

- For the Guest OS, I want to disable everything except the "VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver". I currently do this manually.
- When I switch to the Host OS, I want to disable the "VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver", and enable all the other drivers:

  - Client for Microsoft Networks
  - Internet Protocol Version 6(TCP/IPv6)
  - Internet Protocol Version 4(TCP/IPv4)
  - ...(NetBios etc)

I believe I should be able to use "netsh .." or "wmic nic." to  do  this. 
So far the command:
netsh interface dump > configA.dat
and 
netsh -f configA.dat
or
netsh -f configB.dat
do  not make  the changes... I still have to do this manually.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of Local Area Connection Properties]

Answer (score 0):

This is the script I came up with which solves the problem for me:

```
#######################################################################
# SelectLAN.ps1
#
#  Simple? Windows PowerShell Script to select between 
#   1) Win2012 HOST system controlling 10.1.1.100 (Tester network)
#   2) Win2003 VirtualBox Guest Operating System controlling 10.1.100  (Tester network)
#
########################################################################
#
#  Revision History
#  0.0 10/18/2016  R.Youngblood 
#
########################################################################

function win2012 {
  ""  
  " Applying WIN2012 LAN Configuration"
  ""
  " Enabling Local Reciept of IPV4 and IPV6 packets"
  " Disable VirtualBox Driver"
  Get-NetAdapterBinding -InterfaceAlias "LAN2"
  Enable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID     oracle_vboxnetlwf
  Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID ms_rspndr
  Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID ms_lltdio
  Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID ms_implat
  Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID ms_msclient
  Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID vflt
  Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID ms_pacer 
  Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID ms_server
  Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID ms_tcpip
  Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID ms_tcpip6 
}



function win2003VM {
   ""
   " Applying WIN2003 LAN Configuration"
   ""
   " Disable Local IPV4 and IPV6 Packet reciept"
   " Enable VirtualBox Driver"
   ""
   Get-NetAdapterBinding -InterfaceAlias "LAN2"
   Disable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID oracle_vboxnetlwf
   Enable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID ms_rspndr
   Enable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID ms_lltdio
   Enable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID ms_implat
   Enable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID ms_msclient
   Enable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID vflt
   Enable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID ms_pacer
   Enable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID ms_server
   Enable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID ms_tcpip
   Enable-NetAdapterBinding -Name "LAN2" -ComponentID ms_tcpip6
}





function endprint {
  " Final Network Adapter configuration:"
  Get-NetAdapterBinding -InterfaceAlias "LAN2"
  " -- Done"
}

cls
""
"IP Configuration"
""
" 1. Win2012                 Owns 10.1.1.100 IP"
" 2. Win2003 Virtual Machine Owns 10.1.1.100 IP"
""

$option = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter your choice'
if ($option -eq 1 ) { win2012 }
if ($option -eq 2 ) { win2003VM }
endprint
```