# How to browse the net safely with Windows computers?

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox, security, ransomware

I have Windows 7 and Window 10 laptops. I'm thinking of a **bullet-proof** way to protect the computers from network threats such as the ransomware attacks that have been running wild during the last few days and months.

I'm thinking of a way to use the laptops' original Windows operating system just to handle the hardware - display, keyboard, mouse and audio - but limit networking to only some isolated environment inside the machine - a virtual machine or something like that.

Ideally Windows should not see any kind of network connection - there would be no way in and no way out. But networking would be possible from inside the virtual machine. Then, if some ransomware like Petya or Wannacry or something gets in, it would devastate only the virtual machine, not the real hardware.

How could this be achieved? The only idea I have come up with myself is to expose a serial port to VirtualBox and use it to make a PPP internet connection to a Linux box that acts as a network server. Or use the serial port with an ancient external telephone modem.

[image: PPP internet connection to VirtualBox]

Would this protect the Win10 PC from ransomware attacs? Can anyone think of anything more practical?

Comment: The only bullet-proof way to protect your computer is not to connect it to the internet, and not to turn it on. Everything else has some risk involved. As such, this question is too broad to be answered authoritatively or even helpfully.

Answer (score 0):

You're going at this as such a means that Ransom-ware and other threats **only** occur via the Internet. Your first step of attack should be anti-virus.

First thing I'd suggest is to enable "[Shadow Copy (VSS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968832(v=vs.85).aspx)" on your PC, and have an active backup solution, even to a local drive with permissions.

Secondly, it depends on how far you wish to proceed with your network issue. For example, if you want to mitigate the threats of attacks on the PC, the first step is to restrict the permissions of the user you're logged into, and using `runas` to perform an administrative functions.

Now, as for the method to restrict the access to the internet, Virtual Box is going to need to use NIC Pass-through or a direct NAT; this question seems sufficient - [VirtualBox: Set Network Adaptor for exclusive use of Guest VM](https://superuser.com/questions/278515/virtualbox-set-network-adaptor-for-exclusive-use-of-guest-vm) which states the following:

> I set the guest VM's Virtualbox configuration I set the networking
>   mode to "Bridged", and attached to my host's LAN connection.
>
> On the host, I disabled all but "VirtualBox Bridged Networking Driver"
>   in the connection properties list.
>
> I was subsequently able to access the internet from my guest OS, but
>   not from the host.

Another method to string perhaps is to set your host file to block all network connections (as in, reroute to `127.0.0.1`), whilst not impeding the network connection of the Virtual Box (unless you're bridging your connection).

**How I would approach your issue**

Now, to help mitigate the threats you're concerned about, I have one suggestion:

> Focus more on recovery if set event occurs, as opposed to preventing it

Now I say this because there is **no such thing** as a bullet proof system. You need a fall-back plan.

- Enable VSS for file-to-file backups of corruption;
- Run a strict backup process of data (preferably to an on-site NAS);
- Ensure you use a decent Anti-Virus (preferably with a bundled Firewall) and keep it current;
- Restrict User Permissions should a virus attempt to run and lastly;
- Encrypt your files with a program such as AxCrypt.

Installing an OS takes all of 15 minutes on a modern PC, but recouping all the data failed to backup could take more time.

**Bullet Proof Network Attacks**

Again, there is no such thing. However, if your host PC only needs to access a very small subset of websites I would recommend:

- Host file all content and add **only your** required websites to the exception list;
- Using either Windows Firewall or another application, make application specific rules for accessing URLs, IPs and Ports

If you're only concerned with network attacks on a Windows Environment, perhaps running a Linux **dual boot** is a safer method for you, if possible.

All in all these are suggestions and opinions, there is no "right or wrong" answer to your opinion, so best of luck.